# Recursively file search not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, file, search

What i wanna do is to recursively search for some files on the *external sd-card*. The problem is that the code is looking ok, but (assuming `.txt` files) it only shows me 7 files out of **100+** that are being spread throughout folders.

The code is this:

```
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    void makelist(File file){
        if(file.isFile()){
            if(SimpleAdapter.getFileType(file)==null) 
                       mis.add(file);
            else if(SimpleAdapter.getFileType(file).equalsIgnoreCase("text"))  
                       doc.add(file);
        }else if(file.isDirectory()){
            for(File f:file.listFiles())
                makelist(f);
        }
    }
```

Any idea how could i make it run correctly?

Comment: Perhaps there is something your missing in your `getFileType()` method?

Comment: the getFileType() is 
 public static String getFileType(File f){
  String Name = f.getName();
if(f.getName().endsWith(".txt") || Name.endsWith(".TXT") || Name.endsWith(".inf") || Name.endsWith(".INF"))
   return "text";
  return null;
 }

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are building two lists (misc files and doc files), try with below code which all all files other than text files to misc and text files to doc.

```
if(SimpleAdapter.getFileType(file) ==  null || !SimpleAdapter.getFileType(file).equalsIgnoreCase("text"))
   mis.add(file);
else 
   doc.add(file);
```

Not sure why it is not working for you. Tried a test program and it worked perfectly...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class FileChecker 
{

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleAdapterTest adapter = new SimpleAdapterTest();

    adapter.makelist(new File("C:\\MYFolder"));
    adapter.showList();
}

}

class SimpleAdapterTest
{
List<File> mis = new ArrayList<File>();
List<File> doc = new ArrayList<File>();


public static String getFileType(File f) 
{
    String Name = f.getName();
    if (f.getName().endsWith(".txt") || Name.endsWith(".TXT")
            || Name.endsWith(".inf") || Name.endsWith(".INF"))
        return "text";

    return null;
} 

public void makelist(File file){
    if(file.isFile()){
        if(SimpleAdapterTest.getFileType(file)==null) 
                   mis.add(file);
        else if(SimpleAdapterTest.getFileType(file).equalsIgnoreCase("text"))  
                   doc.add(file);
    }else if(file.isDirectory()){
        for(File f:file.listFiles())
            makelist(f);
    }
}

public void showList()
{
    for(File miscFile : mis)
    {
        System.out.println("Misc files = " + miscFile.getName());
    }

    for(File docfile : doc)
    {
        System.out.println("Doc files = " + docfile.getName());
    }

}
```

}